# How to start a new gms/firebase Task using an Executor?

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a NetworkStuffTask which must be excuted on a separate Thread.
I know how to do that when it's launched as a continuation of another:

```
anotherTask.continueWithTask(executor, aTask -> new NetworkStuffTask(aTask.getResult())
```

How to do that when the NetworkStuffTask is the first Task we run?
Haven't found anything in [the docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/package-summary).
Only thing I've come up with is first starting another task so this can be a continuation:

```
Task<TheInputType> starterTask = Tasks.<TheInputType>forResult(data);
Task<TheOutputType> actualTask = starterTask.continueWithTask(
        executor, dumTask -> new NetworkStuffTask(dumTask.getResult()))
```

Comment: Not very clear what you are asking. Have you used AsyncTask? What do you mean by "entry point"?

Comment: @IshitaSinha AsyncTasks have nothing to do with 
com.google.android.gms.tasks The latter can be chained, and I'm asking how to make one run on a separate Thread when it's the FIRST or only one in a chain (question edited to replace "entry point" with that explanation). For any other scenario, we can specify an Executor.